# tensorflow beginner tutorial - read_data_sets fails

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, mnist

I'm trying to run the [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html) on Linux. I installed `gcc`, `cython`, `numpy`, `six`.

I can import the data but there seems to be some kind of problem unpacking it.

Can anyone help?

---

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jun 22 2015, 19:43:34)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.   
>>> import g3doc.tutorials.mnist.input_data as input_data
>>> mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
Successfully downloaded train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz 9912422 bytes.
Extracting MNIST_data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "g3doc/tutorials/mnist/input_data.py", line 175, in read_data_sets
    train_images = extract_images(local_file)
  File "g3doc/tutorials/mnist/input_data.py", line 60, in extract_images
    buf = bytestream.read(rows * cols * num_images)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 263, in read
    chunk = self.extrabuf[offset: offset + size]
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
>>> mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
Extracting MNIST_data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "g3doc/tutorials/mnist/input_data.py", line 175, in read_data_sets
    train_images = extract_images(local_file)
  File "g3doc/tutorials/mnist/input_data.py", line 60, in extract_images
    buf = bytestream.read(rows * cols * num_images)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 263, in read
    chunk = self.extrabuf\[offset: offset + size]
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

---

Comment: Thanks for raising this issue - the fix is now upstream: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/a4806a3fba7c00bea3e7022477339b2d09539751

Comment: See also: [tflearn issue](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/issues/584)

Answer (score 9):

This appears to be an issue with the latest version of Numpy. A [recent change](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/c87c7a612ee7f90281797e447255c402b099c73a#diff-ed156d214ca580fa436c7859cd48d21cL1028) made it an error to treat a single-element array as a scalar for the purposes of indexing.

I have made the relevant change to the upstream TensorFlow code, but in the meantime you can edit [this line in `input_data.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/bb7a7a8858dc18ba733ed64e0733e27a4224ece8/tensorflow/g3doc/tutorials/mnist/input_data.py#L45) (L45) to be the following (adding `[0]` at the end of the line):

```
return numpy.frombuffer(bytestream.read(4), dtype=dt)[0]
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! But When i hack L60, i then get a similar traceback  on line 62, and then when i hack L62 similarly, i get traceback in L263 of gzip.py. Shall i pull from upstream and try it instead?

Comment: Yes - we fixed `_read32()` to return an int rather than an array, which should fix things for you. Thanks again for the report!

Comment: I updated the answer to show the correct fix instead - for posterity - but pulling from upstream is probably still the way to go.